# Attaching many volumes to an EC2 instance

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, mount

I've got an EC2 instance running Ubuntu and want to attach some 50-60 EBS volumes to it. However, the EC2 console says I can use only /dev/sdf through /dev/sdp, so I'm limited to 11 volumes. Is there a way around this limitation?

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-attaching-volume.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any specific reason you want to attach that many separate volumes to the instance?

I believe what you want are lots of partition in your system. But for that you don't need that much EBS volumes to be attached to the instance.

You can simply attach a bigger Volume and then partition it at the OS level, using utilities like fdisk or parted.

Please let me know if there is any specific reason you want to attach that many volumes or else this solution should work.

Comment: In fact, I have several instances that exchange some big data between each other. Moving a volume from one instance to another is much faster than copying data across network.

Comment: That's very true and for that you will need different volumes. But at the same time, in your scenario, I would have used some centralized storage instead of using separate volumes to share or move data among different instances. Anyways, that's all depends on your architecture, which I am not sure of, so just a small suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The cause for this particular question is apparently the misleading nature of the EC2/EBS web console. It seems to explicitly say that you can't attach past `sdp` (`xvdp`), but if you just ignore its suggestions and manually type in `sdq`, it will probably just work.

That will work up to `sdz` (`xvdz`). After that, http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/device_naming.html says on modern-day HVM instances one can use: `xvd[b-c][a-z]` which would give you another 62 slots.

(This topic is also discussed at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11042413/what-is-the-max-number-of-attached-volumes-per-amazon-ec2-instance)